# In Yesod, can we invoke a method that returns Handler () from a method that returns only IO ()

Tags: haskell, yesod

Please forgive my ignorance but, is there is way to invoke a method that returns `Handler ()` from a method that returns only `IO ()`

For example consider these two methods

```
onReceiveMessage :: IO ()
onReceiveMessage = do
  _ <- putStrLn "Received Message" 
  _ <- doSomething
  return ()

doSomething :: Handler ()
doSomething = return ()
```

This does not seem to compile.  I tried to compile it in a few different ways but all in vein.  I am sure it must be possible but just don't know how.

Any Idea?

---

### UPDATE

Expanding on the previous example, lets say I have another function that takes in a value of the previous function and returns IO ().  That also does not work.

```
onReceiveMessage :: IO ()
onReceiveMessage = 
    doSomething >>= doSomethingElse

doSomething :: Handler MessageStatus
doSomething = return MessageStatus.Success

doSomethingElse :: MessageStatus -> IO ()
doSomethingElse _ = return ()
```

This also does not seem to work. To invoke an IO action from Handler is possible using the liftIO function for e.g. the below function compiles and works fine.  It invokes a IO () action from a function that returns Handler MessageStatus.  This is achieved using the liftIO function.

```
doSomething' :: Handler MessageStatus
doSomething' = (liftIO $ putStrLn "hello world") >> return MessageStatus.Success
```

Do we have something similar to invoke Handler action from IO?

---

### UPDATE 2

Giving more context and explaining how I solved the problem.

I was trying to listen to RabbitMQ using the [amqp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp-0.1/docs/Network-AMQP.html) package in an Yesod application.

- When I receive a message a callback is invoked.
- The callback needs to have the signature `(Message, Envelope) -> IO ()`.
- From the callback I needed to execute some SQL's.
- Now I didn't want to write code to parse the config file and manage my own Connection Pool.
- Hence, I wanted to hookup my code with the method provided by Yesod called `runDB`.
- But since its return values are wrapped in `Handler` I was not able to invoke it as is from the message callback.

What I ended up doing was

- Get hold of the `App` (`Foundation`) object while its being built in the `Application.hs` and passed it to my code.
- Then create a [curried function](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) for the message callback
- In the curried function I hold on to the config object that was already build by Yesod, while building the foundation
- It was breeze after I figured this out, Using the config object I could read all my settings from the settings.yml and even keep a parallel connection pool.
- This connection pool will be used to fire all my queries from the message callback.
- Not only this, but because I used this approach, I get logging for free and I can see all my queries on the console without writing a single line of code.

Overall I feel I might have over complicated things but currently I do not know of any better way of doing this. If anyone has a better idea, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your indentions look off.  White space in Haskell is important.  But more importantly, every statement in a single monadic action has to be within the same monad:

```hs
onReceiveMessage :: IO ()
onReceiveMessage = do
    putStrLn "Received Message" :: IO ()
    doSomething :: Handler ()   -- Illegal! Must be type IO ()
    return () :: IO ()

doSomething :: Handler ()
doSomething = return ()
```

So no, you can not return a handler from an `IO` action.

---

UPDATE

The `Handler` type is actually an alias for a more complex type which you can think of as "wrapping" the IO monad.  What it allows you to do is "lift" an IO action into the `Handler` monad, but this only goes one way.  In order to convert a `Handler` action into an `IO` action, there is usually a function provided by the library that is something like `runHandler :: Handler [-> other args] -> IO ()`.  I'm not particularly familiar with Yesod, but the pattern is similar across many libraries.  This function is used to convert an entire `Handler` action into an `IO` action, and is usually reserved for running the server itself.

The complicated answer is that the `Handler` type is what is known as a *monad transformer*.  They can be pretty tricky to learn at first, but you can just think of it as a monad that contains another monad.  Monads can not perform operations outside themselves, so `IO` can't perform `Handler` actions, but since `Handler` contains `IO` inside it, an `IO` action can be "lifted" up a level.  The really useful thing about monad transformers is that they can be layered indefinitely, and it essentially lets you compose the behavior of different monads together.  For instance, imagine if you had a `Maybe` action, but you also wanted `State` functionality, `Writer` functionality, and `IO` functionality.  With monad transformers, this becomes possible, if a bit more complex.  However, the order in which these are composed can often matter, since operations can be lifted, but not lowered.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I have updated the question with more information to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense now.  I will try the runHandler method and will update with my findings.

Comment: I will accept this answer as runHandler method does exist and does what I need but its not very straight forward (atleast for a nob like me).  I have updated the question with what I ended up doing.  However for the context of this question, the solution provided by this answer is appropriate.  Hence, accepting the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions you can use `Yesod.Core.Handler.handlerToIO` to get back into your cozy Handler stack.

But i recommend decoupling messaging and processing:

```
getOneMsg :: Channel -> Text -> Handler (Message, Envelope)
getOneMsg chan queue = liftIO $ do
    mbox <- newEmptyMVar
    tag <- consumeMsgs chan queue NoAck (putMVar mbox)
    reply <- takeMVar mbox
    cancelConsumer chan tag
    return reply

myHandler = do
    ... regular handler code ...
    (msg, env) <- getOneMsg chan queue
    ... regular handler code ...
```